# Python Tkinter Dynamic Scrollbar Resizing Issue

Tags: python, tkinter, resize

I write on Python an GUI with dynamic resizing, I mean, if the height of all the elements of the window are more than the height of the window, the scrollbar appears on the right side, but if I resize the window and the height of all elements are less than the window, the scrollbar disappear.
I have made this using the `<Configure>` event. This is part of the code I have used:

```
    mycanvas = Canvas(self.parent,bd=0,highlightthickness=0,relief='flat')
    sbar = tk.Scrollbar(mycanvas,orient='vertical')
    sbar.config(command=mycanvas.yview)
    mycanvas.config(yscrollcommand=sbar.set)

    def canvasscroll(event):
        mycanvas.yview('scroll',int(-1*(event.delta/120)), "units")
    def resizecanvas(event):
        if self.mainyposition > event.height: #mainyposition is the addition of the height of all widgets in screen
            sbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        else:
            sbar.forget()
        print(event.height)

    self.widgetname.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", canvasscroll)
    self.widgetname.bind_all("<Configure>", resizecanvas)
```

Everything works well except for two issues:

First of all, when the window starts, the `<Configure>` event is called a few times, and print the height on screen, but the last time its called before the program stills on stand by is a height that is not the correct height of the window, so this causes that it shows unnecesarily the scrollbar. The problem solves itself once I resize the window and the event runs again, but the first run it fails doing this. Any way to solve this?

And second, during the resizing, the console doesn't show any errors, but when I close the window, it shows me an `Exception in Tkinter Callback` that references the `pack()` method of the scrollbar. I don't know how to solve this... The errors are this:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
      return self.func(*args)
  File "Y:\Factory\GLP2-e Admin (Todos los archivos)\Nueva Interfaz\classmain.py", line 108, in resizecanvas
      sbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2140, in pack_configure + self._options(cnf, kw))
  _tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!canvas.!scrollbar"
  Exception in Tkinter callback
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
      return self.func(*args)
  File "Y:\Factory\GLP2-e Admin (Todos los archivos)\Nueva Interfaz\classmain.py", line 108, in resizecanvas
  sbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2140, in pack_configure + self._options(cnf, kw))
  _tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!canvas.!scrollbar"
  Exception in Tkinter callback
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
      return self.func(*args)
  File "Y:\Factory\GLP2-e Admin (Todos los archivos)\Nueva Interfaz\classmain.py", line 108, in resizecanvas
      sbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2140, in pack_configure + self._options(cnf, kw))
  _tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!canvas.!scrollbar"
  [Finished in 22.3s]
```

Thanks to everyone.

Comment: auto scrollbar behavior is very tricky to get right, i can't see anything obvious causing your pack issue but there isn't really enough code to try out. i can however point you at my scrolled frame implementation https://github.com/JamesGKent/python-tkwidgets/blob/master/scrolledframe.py that wraps a frame into a canvas, and that canvas along with two scrollbars into an outer frame, the default behavior of which is to auto hide both scrollbars and only show each one when the inner frame size exceeds that of the canvas, hopefully that helps you

Comment: I've been looking around the code and trying to find the error, and the error is present when I call some method of `sbar` into the event function. Everything works well but when I close the window it returns the errors above... Could be something relating to locals or globals into the event function instead of the class that it is?

Comment: well your code is saying bad windowname, implying that at the point the code is called the scrollbar has been destroyed, this implies that closing the windows is somehow calling your event, so changing the scope won't fix that, only guarding against invoking it when closing the window will prevent it

Comment: Yes, yes, that's what I was thinking, that closing the window calls the event, and that there is no widgets, returns the error. Is there any way to cancel an event binding when the window closes?

Comment: there is an `unbind` method that just takes the event as an argument, and you can catch the window closing with `tk.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', func)`

Comment: I have tried it before read your comment and it works without errors. Both have came to the same conclussion. Thank you very much for your help.
Now, I will try to resolve the first run call to the event.